# Store Auth Token in Cache .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net, authentication, .net-core

I have .NET Core 3.1 project where I have to call third party service to get the data. That service requires an auth token so I need to call a API to get token first.

I would like to store the token in MemCache for x minutes so I do not have to keep doing that with every call.

My question is what is the best practice of saving and calling the Auth Token Endpoint. Should I do that in the constructor of a service or GetAuthToken method should be called in every service method

```
public class ProductService: IProductService
    {

        private readonly ILogger _logger;    
        private readonly IThirdService _thirdService;
        private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
        public string token;


        public ProductService()
        {
             //Should save token here 
            //token = GetToken();
        }

       
        private async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            var cacheKey = "authToken";
            var token = "";
            if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out token))
            {
                token = await _thirdService.GetAuthTokenAsync();
                var cacheExpiryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
                {
                    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3350),
                    Priority = CacheItemPriority.High,
                    SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3320)
                };
                //setting cache entries
                _memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, token, cacheExpiryOptions);
            }
            return token;
        }
        public async Task<something> GetSomething()
        {
           //Should call Token method here or not?
          //
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you have local variable you will set it in constructor. So you can use token in every function and you don't have to call it in every function. 
If your Service has many function calls, what have no use of token in one request, then do it only in function you have to use the token.

Comment: Can I make constructor async to call async method? Can you show an example @OliverBeck

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with dependency injection

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{

    private readonly ILogger<ProductService> _logger;
    private readonly IThirdService _thirdService;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private readonly _token;


    public ProductService(
        ILogger<ProductService> logger,
        IThirdService thirdService,
        IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _thirdService = thirdService;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;

        _token = GetTokenAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        var cacheKey = "authToken";
        var token = "";
        if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out token))
        {
            token = await _thirdService.GetAuthTokenAsync();
            var cacheExpiryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
            {
                AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3350),
                Priority = CacheItemPriority.High,
                SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3320)
            };
            //setting cache entries
            _memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, token, cacheExpiryOptions);
        }
        return token;
    }

    public async Task<Something> GetSomethingAsync()
    {
        // use _token
    }

}
```

You have to register it scoped in startup.cs .

```
services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
```

In my opinion i name classes that get data not Service, i name it Repository.